# PSQL nodejs variable undefined

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql

I have a problem with my function to get all articles from my database.

Articles database:
id |  title   | price |  description

images database: 
id | articleid | name

When I log the data 'articles' it's undefined.

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM articles', function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (result.rowCount != 0) {
            var articles = [];
            result.rows.forEach(function (entry) {
                client.query('SELECT name FROM images WHERE articleid = $1', [entry.id], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    var article = [];
                    var images = [];

                    result.rows.forEach(function (entry) {
                        images.push(entry.name);
                    });

                    article = entry;
                    article.images = images;

                    articles.push(article);

                });
            });
            console.log(articles);
            res.send(articles);
        }

        res.send();
    });
```

Comment: you better join two tables in select then loop it in js I suppose like `SELECT a.*,i.name FROM articles a join images i on i.articleid = a.id`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Sequelize as a ORM for your application, since it makes easy to handle your database and even let you query database directly:

For instance, you would need to define a class for every table in your database:

*models/article.js*

```
var Article  = sequelize.define("Article", {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, name: 'name' },
  ...
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Article.hasMany(models.Image);
    }
  }
});
```

Notice you define a one to many relationship with your Image table.

*models/image.js*

```
var Image = sequelize.define("Image", {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
  url: { type: DataTypes.STRING, name: 'name' },
  ...
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Image.belogsTo(models.Article);
    }
  }
});
```

Notice you indicate a one to one relationship back to the Article.

Finally, you can use above classes to query your database:

```
app.get(function(req, res, next) {
  models.Article
  .findAll({
      includes: [{
        model: models.Image
      }]
  })
  .then(function(articles) {
    res.json(articles);
  });
});
```

In this case you query all articles and include the list of images that belong to that article.

You could even run a plain query following next syntax:

```
var queryString = 'select * from Article a join Image i on a.id = i.articleId where articleId = :articleId';

models.sequelize
  .query(queryString, {
    replacements: { articleId: req.params.id },
    type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
  })
  .then(function(articles) {
    res.json(articles)
  });
```

Here you can find an example of how to configure sequelize in your project: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/